# Which determiner to use with degrees: “a” or “my/his/her/your”?

Tags: word-choice, articles, possessive-determiners

Examples:

- She has **a** PhD in biophysics.
- She has **her** PhD in biophysics.

And:

- He has **a** black belt in judo.
- He has **his** black belt in judo.

Comment: Normally the determiner would be ***a/an***, but for stylistic reasons you might use a possessive pronoun in some contexts. For example, *Sure, he has his highly-paid job, but he does not enjoy life, and I do not envy him.* The exact nuance implied by using an "optional" possessive depends on the exact context - often it's somewhat belittling, but it can be approbatory: *Every member of our community has his innate sense of self-worth*.

Answer (score 1):

One would use *a* in the case where none of the people involved in the conversation has a similar qualification: She has a Ph.D. in biophysics, (me, I have an O-level).

But if everyone involved had a qualification of similar standing, you might use the possessive: She has her black belt in judo (mine is in origami).